# AWS Amplify Rewrite not working for https non-www to www

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I want to redirect from non-www to www and HTTP to HTTPS. I resolved HTTP to HTTPS by just doing permanent forwarding 301 in GoDaddy, but I can't redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

I tried the following (also tried the Rewrite 200):
[image]

which results in:
[image]

Any thoughts on why the redirect or rewrite is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 302 code instead of using 301.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: `You can try with 302 code instead of using 301.` **Why?** You may be right and this might be the solution, but you need to tell why this is the way - otherwise it's just like a random answer.

Comment: No idea why but using 302 worked for me too. I was just about to take a baseball bat to my monitor until I found this post! xD

Answer (score -1):

[The Amazon forum on Github has a possible solution](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/977):

Try adding the following to the rewrites and redirection rules (using your own domain).

```
[
    {
        "source": "https://example.com",
        "target": "https://www.example.com",
        "status": "302",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404-200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

GoDaddy don`t support ANAME for root domain. Only for subdomains. Solved this problem by transferring DNS control to Amazon Route53

https://jryancanty.medium.com/domain-by-godaddy-dns-by-route53-fc7acf2f5580